# "on error goto" glitch. How to deal with a consecutive error and ignoring last row command

Tags: excel, vba, onerror

I am just learning the abc on vba

I have been working with this code, to auto-populate a list based on 2 others.
I have a client list, each client has a consultant, I needed to populate the team each client belonged to, and managed to do this using VLookUp application to relate consultant-manager-team.

So when we have a new consultant on board and has not been added to the "consultant-manager" list,
obviously, I get an error. I tried fixing it with "On Error Resume Next", but it just populated the cell with the error using the last valid team name and went on.
So I inserted a handler (see code below), for it to leave the cell blank and move on, it works fine when there is one error, but when there were 2 continuous errors:

1. The macro would leave the first one in blank but populated the second cell with an error using the last valid team name.
2. It keeps populating even after the list ended, ignoring the condition I gave it for the loop (NumRows in code below).

Could any one of you gods guide me on how to redact the error handling process?

```
Sub populateteam()
    Dim wbFollowUp As Workbook
    Dim wbList As Workbook
    
    Set wbFollowUp = ThisWorkbook
    Set wbList = Workbooks.Open("C:\<folders>\CSTeams.xlsx")
    
    Dim wsAkasaka As Worksheet
    Dim wsList As Worksheet
    
    Set wsAkasaka = wbFollowUp.Worksheets("Akasaka")
    Set wsList = wbList.Worksheets("All Japan")
    
    wbFollowUp.Activate
    
    Dim consultant As String
    Dim manager As String
    Dim team As String
    
    Dim x As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    NumRows = Range("b2", Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    For x = 1 To NumRows    
        consultant = wsAkasaka.Range("b" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value

        On Error GoTo handler:
        manager = Application.VLookup(consultant, wsList.Range("a13:c250"), 3, False)
        team = Application.VLookup(manager, wsList.Range("e2:F11"), 2, False)
        'The name of the manager in the consultant list and in the team list should be exactly the same,
        'including spaces before and after
        
        If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then
            ActiveCell.Value = team
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
handler:
    ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need an `Exit Sub` before your error handler, or it will run regardless.

Comment: Thanks, I wrote in `Exit Sub` as written below, but the 2 problems keep happening. `Exit Sub
handler:
ActiveCell.Value = ""
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Resume Next

End Sub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error handling is not working as you expect. If you read the documentation of the [Resume Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/resume-statement) it says `Resume Next` does the follwing:

> Execution resumes with the statement immediately following the statement that caused the error.

So if an error occured in `manager = Application.VLookup(consultant, wsList.Range("a13:c250"), 3, False)` because the `consultant` could not be found. It will resume with the **next** line which is `team = Application.VLookup(manager, wsList.Range("e2:F11"), 2, False)` but since `manager` was not retrieved this runs into the error handler again. And it proceeds again with the **next* line which is `If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then`.

So the actual problem is that you use `.Select` and `ActiveCell`. You might benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Instead of using `.Select` reference your cells directly (see code below):

```
Option Explicit

Public populateteam()
    Dim wbFollowUp As Workbook
    Set wbFollowUp = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim wbList As Workbook
    Set wbList = Workbooks.Open("C:\<folders>\CSTeams.xlsx")
    
    Dim wsAkasaka As Worksheet
    Set wsAkasaka = wbFollowUp.Worksheets("Akasaka")
    
    Dim wsList As Worksheet
    Set wsList = wbList.Worksheets("All Japan")
    
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = wsAkasaka.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To LastRow ' start in row 2 and run to last row if you want to start from the active cells row use `ActiveCell.Row` instead of 2
        Dim consultant As String
        consultant = wsAkasaka.Cells(iRow, "B").Value

        Dim manager As Variant
        manager = Application.VLookup(consultant, wsList.Range("A13:C250"), 3, False)
        
        If Not IsError(manager) Then
            Dim team As Variant
            team = Application.VLookup(manager, wsList.Range("E2:F11"), 2, False)
            'The name of the manager in the consultant list and in the team list should be exactly the same,
            'including spaces before and after
            
            If Not IsError(team) Then
                With wsAkasaka.Cells(iRow, "B")  'replace "B" with the column letter where you want to write your team!
                    If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                        .Value = team
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

> **Note that the `"B"` in the `With` statement needs to be adjusted to the column where you want to write the `team` value!**

In the code you see I eliminated `ActiveCell` and `.Select` entirely by full cell references like `wsAkasaka.Cells(iRow, "B").Value` it now uses the index `iRow` from the loop.

Also I removed the error handling and check if the lookup came up with an result (this is more performant than error handling and easier to accomplish). So the code only proceeds with the following step if the lookup was successful. If an error occured it proceeds automatically with the next row `Next iRow`.

Just a side note. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. Therefore row counting variables need to be declared `Long`. Since there is [no benefit in using `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/26409520#26409520) in VBA I recommend always to use `Long` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! This code looks so much refined. Though I have to admit I had to read the code and your explanation like 4 times to actually understand it. (I feel like I am trying to keep and accounting book when all I can do is count to 10).

Answer (score 1):

If you step through your code line-by-line you can find these issues yourself.  In fact, whenever error handling isn't working as you expect it to, you should step through your code line-by-line to see exactly what is happening.

For your first issue,

> The macro would leave the first one in blank but populated the second cell with an error using the last valid team name.

Think about what's happening as your code runs when you have a new consultant:

1. The line `manager = Application.VLookup(consultant, wsList.Range("a13:c250"), 3, False)` will throw an error.  Note that the value of `manager` will **NOT** update, and will therefore stay as the value it was previously.
2. Your code goes through the `handler` block, populate the cell with "", move to the next cell down, and then that `Resume Next` line takes you directly to `team = Application.VLookup(manager, wsList.Range("e2:F11"), 2, False)`
3. Now, the value of `manager` is the same as it was in the last run, so the value of `team` will be the same as it was last run.

I'm a little confused by your `If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then` loop, so this advice might not be what you're trying to accomplish, but I recommend adding an `Else` clause to your `If` statement, and then moving the line `team = Application.VLookup(manager, wsList.Range("e2:F11"), 2, False)` under that  `Else` clause.  This will only write the `team` to a cell when the `manager` value value was updated with an existing `consultant`.

As for your second issue,

> It keeps populating even after the list ended, ignoring the condition I gave it for the loop (NumRows in code below).

have you checked the value of `NumRows`?  This line `Range("b2", Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count` has a value much larger than you think it should be: over 1 million

Comment: Thank you @TehDrunkSailor. I chose to use PeH's solution because it seems fool proof, but your analysis really  helped me understand where I was going wrong, at what made the code so confusing.